# reposting code: cant get the form data via email

Tags: php, html, forms

PROBLEM: I am unable to get the form data submitted by user on my email. When user click on submit, the form refreshes but does not send any email to me.  If anyone of you spot any mistake here. I really thanks in advance.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="content">
      <h1>Contact Us</h1>
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <form action="email.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="Your good name" required>
          <label for="exampleInputName"><i class="icon-tag"></i></label>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="icon-inbox"></i></label>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group textarea">
          <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" name="message" id="exampleInputMessage" placeholder="How can we help your business" required></textarea>
          <label for="exampleInputMessage"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></label>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-large" value="Send Message">   </button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
```

enter code here

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: TangledDemo'; 
$to = 'danish@cloudtechteam.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';


$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

$host = "mail.cloudtechteam.com";
$port = "25";
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
 array ('host' => $host,
 'port' => $port,));
  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if ($_POST['submit']) {              
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: what's the exact problem ?

Comment: pro tip, if your going to ask on S.O hang around, most are answered or at least commented on in seconds. if you leave it to long, every one moves on to other questions.

Comment: You haven't really said what your problem is. Are you getting an error? What have you tried? What have you already searched?

Comment: Problem: I am not getting the submitted form on my email. When user hit the submit button nothing happens.

Comment: Which one of you sending via? As you've got `$stmp` and then check `mail()`?

Comment: Thanks Darren, shall I remove smtp? I put both in hope that it will use either to send but none of that working.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is using a get method, the defualt for a `<form>`.  Change your form to

```
<form role="form" method="post">
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Robbert. First line of my form has the code you mentioned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean?  Your posted code has the form defined as `<form role="form">`.  You're missing the method attribute, and therefore your form is sending the form data using get.  The only way to make your code work is to either change `$_POST` to `$_GET` or add the method attribute.

Comment: Robbert Thanks alot buddy, something works, but now I see thisInternal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: I would remove the SMTP code. It's redundant since you're using the mail function.